# Export settings for Instagram

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

stop me if I'm asking this in the wrong place, but I'm kind of stuck.

Tried uploading a short video to Instagram yesterday - [this one](https://youtu.be/5OHhJi-zijo) - and Instagram just **destroyed** it. Not like 'a few lines unclear' bad, but large, blocky artefacts that stay onscreen for a long time and totally destroy the visuals bad.

First I thought it was a filter I'd put on (in the Instagram app), but then I added it a second time without filter and the same thing happened. [I've deleted both attempts and didn't think to screenshot it while it was up - apologies.]

I've found many people talking about how to improve video quality for Instagram, but nothing about that level of bad. Does anyone have any experience / suggestions of how to stop this from happening? I've seen some mention it should be 30fps (mine was 24) and no bigger than 1080 (mine was 1200 square), though others talk of uploading 4k to get better results. It's a rabbit hole I feel ill-equipped to go down, so I'm open to ideas.

Many thanks!

Andy Redwood

Comment: Not really a question for the Blender stack exchange, but for Instagram you're best off if you pick 1:1 (which you did), 4:5, or 9:16 formats but the trick is that their compression stuff sucks unless you pick specifically 1080x1080 for the 1:1 format, or at least something that's an exact multiple or divider of 1080.

Comment: Thanks Marty - I've made my latest 1080 square to see if it works better.

Comment: I've had trouble with instagram too where the output video is mirrored along the horizontal axis randomly... I remember fixing it by using an online video converter and choose from mp3 to mp3 and using the resulting file. Might loose on quality though